# Python 3: Join method for dictionary Values+Keys

Tags: python, join, dictionary

I have a function called `factors()` that returns a dictionary so that the values are the prime factors, and the values the number of times these appear as factors, for example:

```
factors(100)
```

Will result in:

```
{2: 2, 5: 2}
```

This is because 2**2 + 5**2 = 100

Ok. So now i want the script to print precisely that: `100 = 2**2 + 5**2`

I have tried with this line of code at the end:

```
print('So ' + str(x) + ' = ' + **' + '.join(str(key) + '**' + factors.get(key) for key in factors)**)
```

Here is the code:

```
def factors(x):
    '''
    input: int
    output: list (prime factors of x list)
    '''
    num = 2
    res = x
    factors = {}
    howmany = 0
    while res > 1:
        if res%num == 0:
            if num in factors:
                factors[num] += 1
            else:
                factors[num] = 1
            res /= num
            howmany += 1
            print('Found one! <' + str(num) + '>. With these are ' + str(howmany) + ' prime factors for the momment')
            print(str(factors))
        else:
            num += 1
    print('DONE!')
    return factors
    print('So ' + str(x) + ' = ' + ' + '.join(str(key) + '**' + factors.get(key) for key in factors))
```

Thanks everyone.

EDIT: When I run it it gives me 'return factors' without a problem, but no clue of the last print line, it does not print anything.

P.S.: Sorry if the formatting is not good, I am new to SO

Comment: What does this give you, and how is it wrong?

Comment: As a side note, you can get rid of that whole `if num in factors:` by (a) using `factors.setdefault(num, 0) += 1`, (b) using a `defaultdict(int)` instead of a plain dict, or (c) using a `Counter`. The last one is probably simplest and most appropriate here; look up `collections.Counter` in the docs if it's not obvious how to do that.

Comment: Also for formatting, first c/p your code, select all then press -for windows- ctrl+k or just use code sample button at top. it is 5th from the left.

Comment: Meanwhile, you've shown us your code, but you haven't explained what it does wrong. Does it raise an exception? Then post the exception and traceback. Does it print the wrong thing? Then tell us what you expected and what it prints instead. Also, most of this code is not relevant to your problem. If you stripped it down to just `factors = {2: 2, 5: 2}` and the `print` call, would it demonstrate the same thing? If so, just post that. If not, figure out what else you need to demonstrate the problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on what code to post.

Comment: `+`? I think you have the wrong symbol, because `2**2 + 5**2 ≠ 100`.

Comment: Yes, btw: `2**2+5**2==29`

Comment: As another side note, you can use `factors[key]` to get the value instead of `factors.get(key)`; the only reason for `get` is if you want to get a default value for keys that aren't in the dictionary, but here that isn't a possible problem. And, even more simply, instead of looking up each key, you can just do `for key, value in factors.items()`, and then use `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines:

```
return factors
print('So ' + str(x) + ' = ' + ' + '.join(str(key) + '**' + factors.get(key) for key in factors))
```

means that the `print` statement will never execute, because `return` ends the function. Reverse the two:

```
print('So ' + str(x) + ' = ' + ' + '.join(str(key) + '**' + factors.get(key) for key in factors))
return factors
```

and you should be closer to being on track.

Comment: This was it, such a dumb error! The print statement was almost pefect, i just had to add `str()` to `factors.get(key)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> fact={2: 2, 5: 2}
>>> ' + '.join(['{}**{}'.format(*t) for t in sorted(fact.items())])
'2**2 + 5**2'
```

However, this is not the prime factors of 100. The *correct* answer is:

```
>>> ' * '.join(['{}**{}'.format(*t) for t in sorted(fact.items())])
'2**2 * 5**2'
```

(Multiply, not add)

You can easily check it using [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, starmap(pow, fact.items()))
100
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem (once you format the code properly, and move the `print` before the `return` so it actually runs) is either this:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

… or a different `TypeError` about `+` not knowing how to handle `int` and `str`.

The reason for that is that, inside your `join`, you're doing this:

```
str(key) + '**' + factors.get(key) for key in factors
```

Notice that you did `str(key)`, but you didn't do `str(factors.get(key))`. So, instead of concatenating three strings, you're concatenating two strings and an int.

This can be hard to get right, or at least hard to spot where you got it wrong. This is one of many reasons that string formatting is better than trying to concatenate up a string:

```
'{}**{}'.format(key, factors.get(key))
```

The `format` method automatically converts everything to `str` so you don't have to figure out where it is and isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {2: 2, 5: 2}

# In one line:
b = ' + '.join([str(row) + '**' + str(a[row]) for row in a])
```

This outputs `'2**2 + 5**2'`, i'm sure you can concatenate this with your factors input variable.

This uses pythons amazing generators and the `for` syntax to iterate over all the results and create a list of all the keys concatenated with a `'**'` and the key's value. The resulting list is then join together with the string `' + '`. Pretty simple stuff, you could do a more conventional for loop as well:

```
# In multiple lines:
b = []
for row in a:
    b.append(str(row) + '**' + str(a[row]))

b = ' + '.join(b)
```